# PHP Search Function with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have the following code -

```
<?php # search.inc
error_reporting(E_ALL); // 
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include "connect_to_mysql.php";
?>
<?php # search.inc.php

//header file:
include_once ('./includes/header.inc');
?>
<?php

$terms= $_GET['terms'];
echo "You've searched for: " . $terms;

$sql= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name ='Big Tree'"; 
//-run  the query against the mysql query function 
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // While there are products that match the search criteria, assign their data to a variable and echo their details on a webpage


             $id = $row["id"];
             $product_name = $row["product_name"];
             $price = $row["price"];
             $details = $row["details"];
             $category = $row["category"];
                echo '<br/> <img name="image" src="inventory_images/' . $row['id'] . '.jpg" width="100" height="150"/>';
                echo '<br/>';
                echo '<br/> Product Name: '.$row['product_name'];
                echo '<br/>';
                echo '<br/> <a href="modules/productsdetails.inc.php?id=' . $id . '">Click Here To View Product Page</a>';
                echo '<br/>';
                echo '<br/>';

        }
mysql_close(); //closes the MySQL connection.
?>
<?php
// Include footer file 
include_once ('./includes/footer.inc');
?>
```

As you can see - I've hard coded it to search for "Big Tree". My question is - How do I code it to search for the users input.

I've tried %$terms% but no results are printed.

Comment: You mean `%$terms%`, right?  Surely you wouldn't just write the word `terms` in a string and expect it to know you wanted to inject a variable...  Assuming you did that, you need to use the `LIKE` operator instead of `=`.  Then you need to worry about SQL injection.  Then you need to consider that you might need to combine multiple terms with `OR`.

Comment: Yes - My bad, was meant to be %$terms%. I'll edit the original

Answer (score 1):

You have to concatenate in the query the variable you want to search for

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name ='".$terms."'";
```

or

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE '%".$terms."%'";
```

Comment: I did attempt this - no luck. Didn't return anything.

Comment: type `echo $sql;` the line after the query, run the query directly in the DB, do you have any result or error there?

Comment: It's returning "SQL: Resource id #10"

Comment: you echoed the $result variable, not the $sql. Try to running the query directly into phpmyadmin or a mysql client. To be sure that the query is OK.

Comment: I echoed $sql, not $result. I've tested the "LIKE" query in phpmyadmin and it doesn't return results unless I put the EXACT product name? I'm running mysql 5.0.67

Comment: This doesn't work: `SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE'%Big Tree%'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name ='$terms'";
```

No need to concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the innodb engine on mysql 5.5 or below you'll have to use 'LIKE' like so:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name like '%".$terms."%'";
```

If you're on mysql 5.6 or you're using a myisam table, you can use MATCH AGAINST if you have a fulltext index on the column you're searching.

```
$sql= "SELECT match(product_name) against('".$terms."') as relevance 
FROM products 
WHERE relevance>0 
ORDER BY relevance desc";
```

Please look into parameterized queries or at the very least use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to sanitize your variables.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function for mysql that parses strings with percentage sorting. You can use it if you like.

It can find almost every combination you search for.

### Install

First you need to create a function in mysql. Here is the code for that.
I did it in phpmyadmin

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION search ( search VARCHAR(255), string VARCHAR(255) )
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN

   DECLARE searchlength INT;
   DECLARE charcount INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE ch VARCHAR(10); 

   DECLARE a INT DEFAULT 0; 
   DECLARE b INT DEFAULT 1;
   DECLARE c INT DEFAULT 0; 

   SET searchlength = LENGTH(search);

   WHILE charcount <= searchlength DO 
    SET ch = SUBSTRING(search,charcount,1); 

    IF LOCATE(ch,string) > 0 THEN 
      IF LOCATE(ch, string) - 1 = b THEN 
        SET c = c + 1; 
      END IF; 
      SET b = LOCATE(ch, string, b);
      SET a = a + 1; 
    END IF;

    SET charcount = charcount + 1;

   END WHILE;

   IF searchlength = a THEN 
    RETURN (c/30)*100; 
   END IF; 
   RETURN -1; 

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can use this function when you make a mysql call from php like this.

```
$searchneedle = "Some string you like to search for"

SELECT name,username 
FROM users 
WHERE search(LOWER('$searchneedle'),CONCAT(LOWER(test_cullum))) > -1
ORDER BY search(LOWER('$searchneedle'),CONCAT(LOWER(test_cullum))) DESC
```